# Start vino-server (VNC) before login on Linux CentOS

Tags: centos, vnc, gnome

I'm using the default vino-server package to access my CentOS 6 workstation via VNC.

It works ok, but only AFTER I locally login on the workstation. I need to have vino-server start BEFORE the login, right at the Gnome login screen where I choose username and password.

Due to personal reasons, I need to use Vino and not vnc-server or any other packages.

I already tried to insert `/usr/libexec/vino-server &` in `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` but this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have a look at the [NX server using FreeNX](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/FreeNX) howto. If it doesn't help you, I suggest reasking on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't agree with this choice, but I reasked on SU.

Comment: Remotely displaying a screen has little to do with servers. It's a more generic topic. Also *"personal reasons"* don't sound too professional to me, unless it's an unfortunate choice of words.

Comment: I answered the question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/a/766306/2357).

Answer (score 1):

look for init script (/etc/init.d) for vino-server

Update :  i hacked an existing startup script, try placing it in /etc/init.d/ and run updaterc.d vnc-server defaults , i have not tried it myself but this is it i have used as skeleton for most of my startup scripts.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          vino-server
# Required-Start:    networking
# Required-Stop:     networking
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: vino-server test script
# Description:       This is a test daemon
#                    This provides example about how to
#                    write a Init script.
### END INIT INFO

# Using the lsb functions to perform the operations.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
# Process name ( For display )
NAME=vino-server
# Daemon name, where is the actual executable
DAEMON=/usr/libexec/vino-server
# pid file for the daemon
PIDFILE=/var/run/vino-server.pid

# If the daemon is not there, then exit.
test -x $DAEMON || exit 5

case $1 in
 start)
  # Checked the PID file exists and check the actual status of process
  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
   status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "$NAME process" && status="0" || status="$?"
   # If the status is SUCCESS then don't need to start again.
   if [ $status = "0" ]; then
    exit # Exit
   fi
  fi
  # Start the daemon.
  log_daemon_msg "Starting the process" "$NAME"
  # Start the daemon with the help of start-stop-daemon
  # Log the message appropriately
  if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON ; then
   log_end_msg 0
  else
   log_end_msg 1
  fi
  ;;
 stop)
  # Stop the daemon.
  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
   status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "Stoppping the $NAME process" && status="0" || status="$?"
   if [ "$status" = 0 ]; then
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
    /bin/rm -rf $PIDFILE
   fi
  else
   log_daemon_msg "$NAME process is not running"
   log_end_msg 0
  fi
  ;;
 restart)
  # Restart the daemon.
  $0 stop && sleep 2 && $0 start
  ;;
 status)
  # Check the status of the process.
  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
   status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "$NAME process" && exit 0 || exit $?
  else
   log_daemon_msg "$NAME Process is not running"
   log_end_msg 0
  fi
  ;;
 reload)
  # Reload the process. Basically sending some signal to a daemon to reload
  # it configurations.
  if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
   start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
   log_success_msg "$NAME process reloaded successfully"
  else
   log_failure_msg "$PIDFILE does not exists"
  fi
  ;;
 *)
  # For invalid arguments, print the usage message.
  echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
  exit 2
  ;;
esac
# Example captured from :http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/
```

& Add it to chkconfig

> sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add  vnc-server
>
> sudo /sbin/chkconfig --list vnc-server
>
> sudo /sbin/chkconfig vnc-server on

Comment: Nice try but there is no init script for vino. [See for yourself](http://s29.postimg.org/qrlgofl3r/z_Screen_Shot27.png)

Comment: @akash, have you tested this script?

Comment: like is said in the beginning, i used my skeleton script and updated it to suit requirement, it would still need someone to run and test. i intended to get @Dr.GianluigiZaneZanettini going.